# 400 bad request to get profile data using retrofit

Tags: android

Log:

> POST http://192.168.225.34:8084/getProfile?emp_pf_no=2323 http/1.1
>   400 Bad Request http://192.168.225.34:8084/getProfile?emp_pf_no=2323 (1067ms)

This is my API interface:

```
 @POST("getProfile")
Call<GetProfileResponse> getProfile(@Query("emp_pf_no") String emp_pf_no);
```

I am getting error while getting response back from server.It is working with Postman post method call but not working in Android

```
private void fetchComplain(String emp_no) {
    Call<GetProfileResponse> call = RestClient.get().getProfile(emp_no);
    Dialogutils.showProgressDialog(this);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<GetProfileResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<GetProfileResponse> call, Response<GetProfileResponse> response) {
            Dialogutils.hideProgressDialog(ProfileActivity.this);
            GetProfileResponse res = response.body();
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                if(res.getStatus()== Constants.SUCCESS){
                    data.clear();
                    data.addAll(res.getData());
                    Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Response:"+res.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,"Error"+res.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,"Error Occured Try Again1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<GetProfileResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Dialogutils.hideProgressDialog(ProfileActivity.this);
            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,"Error Occured Try Again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Postman response:

```
{
"message": "PROFILE VIEW SUCCESSFULLY DONE",
"status": 1,
"data": [
    {
        "emp_id": "1",
        "emp_pf_no": "2323",
        "emp_name": "user",
        "emp_designation": "dev",
        "emp_bu_no": "1234.0",
        "emp_bill_unit_name": "123my",
        "emp_date_of_birth": "12-Dec-2018",
        "emp_date_of_appointment": "05-Aug-1996",
        "emp_date_of_retirement": "02-Aug-2015",
        "emp_aadhaar_number": "545433533333",
        "emp_pan_number": "3543544343",
        "emp_community": "jain",
        "emp_religion": "hindu",
        "emp_sex": "female",
        "emp_mobile_no": "9.479657692E9",
        "emp_phone_no": "7.4122653E8",
        "emp_residential_address": "karmdi road",
        "emp_parmanent_address": "karmdi road",
        "failReason": null
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Does that request need some headers that you are missing?

Comment: And how does postman request look like?

Comment: request key `emp_pf_no` and value `2323`